# NP++ C execute->CreateProcess() failed with error code 2

Tags: c, notepad++, execution

I have a question.
I have used this "tutorial" to compile my c-programms with NP++ and MingW.
http://windowsbro.blogspot.de/2012/10/compile-with-notepad-any-language.html

And my problem is, why i get this error message, even if I have done everything like in this Link.

I have googled and I found out, that I need to edit my Variables. So I added this into my variables.
";C:\MinGW"

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Error code 2 is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. That means that the filename that you specified does not refer to a file.

We cannot see enough information about what you did to be 100% sure what the solution is. Quite possibly `gcc` cannot be found in your search path.

Comment: And I cant finde gcc. How can I add it? Installing other MingW or what?

Comment: Well, that would explain it.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/postdownload?source=dlp here is a tar.bz2 data. How can I use it?

Comment: Is your question related to the Notepad++ error, or do you want installation support for mingw?

Comment: I think, that I havent installed MinGW, like I should. In this case i would say yes. Or both.

Comment: Well, I think I answered the question that you asked. Clearly you need to install a compiler. That's a pre-requisite.

Comment: Yes, i know, but which version?
MinGW is the one i know. If you can recomend some others then tell me.

Comment: MinGW is the best choice for GCC on Windows.

Comment: Ok, i gonna use the MinGW from my tutorial above and try it again

Comment: Ok, now I need a libgmp-10.dll

Comment: Ok, now I get this: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file a.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Surely I answered the question that you asked.